# sql query to loop through select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: sample table]

I'm trying to achieve the following.

1. select distinct values from product name
2. For each product name, if the operation is "taken", "subtract" the quantity. If the operation is "Added", sum the quantity

I want result like this- (some values below are in minus)
helmet     10
goggles   -100
shoes     -120
vest      -30

How will I write an sql query to achieve the above result. I'm on Sql server.

Comment: firstly, could you please provide sample data as a text, not as an image

Comment: Have you tried anything? You want to aggregate your data to get a result row per product. Do you know how to do that? You want to add up values. This is done with `SUM`. You want to either add up the positive value or the negative vale. Decisions can be made with `CASE WHEN` for instance. Does this help?

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Always tag your SQl requests with your DBMS.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I tried to using cursor with no success. I'm using sql server management studio

Comment: Also _specify_ the expected result. And show us your current attempt.

Comment: @jarlh The expected result, I added in the end. I modify this post to show my current attempt.

Comment: When editing, put your data in proper columns. Highlight. Click `{}`.

Comment: There is something you haven't understood yet about SQL. We usually don't write programs looping through datasets and evaluating the single rows. We write a query to tell the DBMS what data we want, not how to achieve this. So, no cursor, no loop, just a query. See Ankit Bajpai's answer.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you simply need a group by clause with some data manipulation here -

```
SELECT productname, SUM(quantity * CASE WHEN operation = 'Taken' THEN -1 ELSE 1 END) amount
  FROM your_table
 GROUP BY productname;
```

Comment: @Charlieface, Agreed and updated the answer.